# Create bulk of model objects unit testing django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-unittest

For testing the pagination behavior of a search view, I have to create a bulk of dummy objects. Is there a more elegant way to create a bulk of objects?

```
create_question('First question.', -1, [Choice(choice_text='First choice.')])
create_question('Second question.', -1, [Choice(choice_text='First choice.')])
# ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use something like [factory_boy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and loop through using range(0, 25) to create the desired number of objects?